# How to use PrimeNG Dropdown in Angular2 Model-driven form?

Tags: angular, dropdown, primeng

Need help with [PrimeNG dropdown](http://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/dropdown) in an Angular2 **model-driven** form.  The PrimeNG documentation I have found only use template-driven forms.

A sample code for the following would help greatly:

1. an Angular model-driven form
2. the form contains one PrimeNG dropdown and a submit button.
3. the dropdown contains 4 cities (Moscow, Istanbul, Berlin, Paris).
4. the user is required to change the selected city (to enable the Submit button).
5. the dropdown can be programatically "initialized" to show one of the cities in the options list (e.g. Berlin) when the form first opens.

Thanks.

Comment: can you write neat and cleans step wise your requirements .. demo is been edited

Comment: @mayur - I clarified the question. What demo are you referring to?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To use the model driven form in Angular2 or Angular4 you'll need to change the dropdown to

```
<p-dropdown [options]="cities" formControlName="selectedCity"></p-dropdown>
```

and instantiate a formGroup on the backend that has the control selectedCity in it like so ...

```
this.angularObjectForm = this.formBuilder.group({selectedCity: [''])}
```

Answer (score 0):

// template handling

```
<form id="demoForm" name="demoForm" [ngFormModel]="demoForm" (submit)="demoForm($event, demoForm)"
 method="post" action="" autocomplete="off">
<h3 class="first">Demo</h3>
<p-dropdown [options]="cities" [(ngModel)]="selectedCity"></p-dropdown>
<span *ngIf="!selectedCity"> Required </span>
<button pButton [disabled]="!selectedCity" type="submit" (click)="onclick()" label="Click"></button>
</form>
```

// Import the files required

```
import {Button} from 'primeng/primeng';
import {Dropdown} from 'primeng/primeng';
```

// class Handling

```
export class MyModel {

    cities: SelectItem[];

    selectedCity: string;

    constructor() {
        this.cities = [];
        this.cities.push({label:'Moscow', value:'1'});
        this.cities.push({label:'Istanbul', value:'2'});
        this.cities.push({label:'Berlin', value:'3'});
        this.cities.push({label:'Paris', value:'4'});
    }

   public demoForm(event: Event, demoForm: ControlGroup): void {
   event.preventDefault();

   // working area //

  }

}
```

Comment: Thanks! The code refers to ngFormModel which makes me think it uses the old (deprecated) Angular2 forms API. Would you know what this would look like in Angular2 RC3 or newer as described [here](https://docs.google.com/document/u/1/d/1RIezQqE4aEhBRmArIAS1mRIZtWFf6JxN_7B4meyWK0Y/pub)

Answer (score -1):

To use Primeng dropdown below is simple explanation:
Install primeng : npm i primeng --save

Then import it to parent module

```
import { DropdownModule } from 'primeng/primeng';
@NgModule({
  imports: [    
    DropdownModule
  ]
});
```

Add below html code to html file:

```
<p-dropdown 
[options]="listVariable" 
placeholder="Select" 
[(ngModel)]="selectedOption" 
(onChange)="onChangeValue()">
```

These are basic steps to implementation..I found very simple practical explanation [here](http://musttoknow.com/how-to-use-angular-4-angular-5-and-angular-6-primeng-dropdown/) He explained it very well.